# Now that Microsoft has shutdown newsgroups

Tags: tapi, newsgroup

...where does one go for help on boutique topics like TAPI, for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that [The Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/) would be an excellent place for boutique programming topics.